# display keywords in a bullet point list in D3.js div append

Tags: javascript, html, css, json, d3.js

i want to show the comma separated values from json as a list in my mouseover tooltip on each node. Currently I have:

```
div.append("div") 
.attr("class", "tooltip")
.style("opacity", 1)
.html("Node name : " + d.NodeName + "<br>" + "Keywords list: " + d.keywords)
```

here is my keywords in json file:

```
"keywords":["one","two","three"]
```

**Question is:**
How to display it in a list like this with bullet points:

```
Node Name : Test Name
Keywords List :
    * one
    * two
    * three
```

currently it is just in one line and keywords are comma separated only.

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: @altocumulus i highlighted the question.

Comment: Loop through the array appending list items.

Comment: @DBS could you please provide an answer, i am newbie and hesitate a lot.

Comment: @marcel If you really want to leverage the potential of D3, I suggest you dive into the concept of [data binding](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#joining-data) used throughout D3. When it comes to D3 explicit looping almost always is a bad idea. Reading the documentation and the examples linked therein should get you started in the right direction.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Untested as I can't see your full solution, but you should be able to build a basic list structure by looping through your array:

```
var keywordList = "<ul>";
for(var i = 0; i < d.keywords.length; i++){
  keywordList += "<li>" + d.keywords[i] + "</li>";
}
keywordList += "</ul>";
```

And then simply add the `keywordList` on the end when you set the HTML, instead of the `d.keywords`:

```
.html("Node name : " + d.NodeName + "<br>" + "Keywords list: " + keywordList)
```

Comment: If my answer is incorrect or a bad way to do this, I'd appreciate if you leave a comment or an alternative answer. Silent down-voting on a working answer doesn't help anyone improve anything.